# How to create dictionary from map class?

Tags: python, dictionary, python-re

I'm trying to introduce escape characters in a dictionary `my_dict` filled with strings (including symbols in both the keys and values).

I know I can do this by using:

```
import re
map(re.escape, my_dict))
```

But how do I reconstitute the dictionary?

Doing this:

```
dict(map(re.escape, my_dict)
```

Gives the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 7; 2 is required
```

Is there a proper way to get the `map()` class back into a dictionary?

Comment: could you give an MRE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is with `map(re.escape, my_dict))`, you're adding escape characters only to the keys.

Example:

```
my_dict = {'hoho.ho':'merry.christmas'}
for i in map(re.escape, my_dict):
    print(i)
```

Output:

```
hoho\.ho
```

You need to zip this with the values to create a dictionary. Try this:

```
new_dict = dict(zip(map(re.escape, my_dict), map(re.escape, my_dict.values())))
```

Output:

```
>>> print(new_dict)
{'hoho\\.ho': 'merry\\.christmas'}
```